# Node app on Docker not reading .env file on start

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to create a container to deploy a web application developed with node and angular.
The goal is to compile the app on the host and copy the result to the container, and then run it.

1. I have created a base image with ubuntu, mysql, nginx and node v18.10.0 (nvm)
2. A startup script on the host:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build client
cd ../erp/
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
ng build --output-hashing all

# Copy build to temp files
cd ../builder/
cp -r ../erp/dist/erp/* tmp/client/

# Build server
cd ../server
npm run build
npm install

# Copy build to temp files
cd ../builder/
cp -r ../server/build/ tmp/server/
cp -r ../server/documents/ tmp/server/
cp -r ../server/node_modules tmp/server/
cp  ../server/.env tmp/server/.env

# Build image
docker build --no-cache -t alouqua/terraos:latest .

# Run container
docker run -d -p 30306:3306 -p 8080:80 -p 8063:443 alouqua/terraos:latest
```

3. The Dockerfile

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                                                                         Dockerfile *                                                                                                
FROM alouqua/terraos:latest AS builder

# COPY server
WORKDIR /home/servers/erp/
COPY tmp/server .

# COPY CLIENT 
WORKDIR /var/www/html/erp/
COPY tmp/client/* .

# COPY NGINX conf
WORKDIR /etc/nginx/sites-available/
COPY nginx/default .
 
# COPY start script
WORKDIR /
COPY start-services.sh start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD /start.sh
```

4. Finally created a start script for the container

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                                                                         Dockerfile *                                                                                                
FROM alouqua/terraos:latest AS builder

# COPY server
WORKDIR /home/servers/erp/
COPY tmp/server .

# COPY CLIENT 
WORKDIR /var/www/html/erp/
COPY tmp/client/* .

# COPY NGINX conf
WORKDIR /etc/nginx/sites-available/
COPY nginx/default .
 
# COPY start script
WORKDIR /
COPY start-services.sh start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD /start.sh
```

The host directory structure:

```
otal 24
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alouqua alouqua  586 Set  1 17:40 build.sh
drwxrwxr-x 2 alouqua alouqua 4096 Ago 31 15:49 databases
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alouqua alouqua  341 Set  1 17:45 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 2 alouqua alouqua 4096 Ago 31 03:28 nginx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alouqua alouqua  307 Set  1 17:30 start-services.sh
drwxrwxr-x 4 alouqua alouqua 4096 Ago 31 15:26 tmp
```

Once the container is on, I can get the start.sh logs:

```
root@b35ca95e0ab2:/# cat /var/log/start.log 
 * Starting nginx nginx
   ...done.
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
2023-09-01 15:48:35 [debug] Server running on port undefined
```

The app is up, but the port is undefined. Node is not reading the .env file, which is in place.

If I start another instance of the app, still port is undufined.

But, if run "npm install" on the app directory, and restart it, now the port number is OK. Why?

Also, I cant "RUN npm install" through Dockerfile (ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127). But it works when I run it manually from the container.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `.env` file? You shouldn't have an envfile within the container; instead use the `--env-file` flag for `docker run`...

Comment: The node app reads environment variables like the apps port from an .env file. Like I said, that works fine when I manually reinstall the node_modules on the container.

Comment: Well, it... probably shouldn't need to do that, since it could use the environment variables Docker can pass down, and those would come from an env file. Also, I feel your run/build stuff is pretty backwards; why is building happening on the host, and the dockerfile just bundles stuff up? Generally you'd build your app in a (possibly multi-stage) dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that the problem is related to nvm. When node is installed via Dockerfile like below, everything is working again:

```
RUN set -uex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg; \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings; \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key \
     | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg; \
    NODE_MAJOR=18; \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install nodejs -y;
```

Now I can use "npm install" on the start.sh script. Node is reading the .env file...and the app is working.

Thanks for the help.